# How to carry query variables from one html page to another?

Tags: python, api, flask, routes

I've been attempting to pass the value q to the second @app.route for some time now but have had no success.

```
@app.route("/results")
def results():
    q = request.args.get('q')
    r = requests.get('http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=MYAPPID&_app_key=MYAPPKEY&requirePictures=true&q= %s' % q)
    data = r.json()
    return render_template("results.html", recipename = data['matches'][0]['recipeName'])

@app.route("/recipe")
def recipe():
    r = requests.get('http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=MYAPPID&_app_key=MYAPPKEY&requirePictures=true&q=  %s' % q)
    data = r.json()
    ID = data["matches"][0]['id']
    rr = requests.get('http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/%s?_app_id=dd85df7a&_app_key=0b187b4352ca796bc89a4600dfad0f06' % ID )
    rdata = rr.json()
    return render_template("recipe.html", url = rdata['attribution']['url'])
```

Any help on how to pass this value would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see that the first route _calls_ the second, so how would it ever pass anything?

Comment: well how would the first route call the second then? this is what's been causing me problems

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The first route does not call the second one, so it's misleading to say that you want to "pass" the data.

It sounds like you want the first route to **save** the data somewhere, and the second route to **read** the data.  There are several ways to do this, such as saving the data in a plain file or in a database. However then you have to worry about one user's data being visible to other users, so it might be best to save the data within the session.

You have another problem: since there is no direct linkage between the two routes, how do you ensure synchronization?  What if the user visits the second route without visiting the first one?

One solution would be to modify your second route so it requires the data to be passed in as an argument, instead of depending on some previous route that may or may not have been visited recently (or ever!)

Comment: thank you how would you go about passing the argument, that's what i've been aiming to do but have been unable to find out how

Comment: The first route already has code to fetch an argument: `q = request.args.get('q')`.  Just use the same code in the second route.  Of course this requires that your users _supply_ that argument when visiting the second route.